# Getting uncaught exception in javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle, exception, plsql

I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}" error in browser console and the below message popup is not showing though all conditions are satisfied.
Can someone point out the error here

*

```
IF (dmd.is_txt(videntifier) = 'TRUE' AND gb = 'S' AND hn AND (vp IS NULL OR vp = '')) THEN     
    htp.p('<script language = "javascript">          if(ghb != null && eff != "" && ghg != "NULL")
         {
          var fhh = confirm("223?");
          if (answer_preorder)
          { 
           theform.ghb.value = ghy;
           </script>');
           bsave := true;
           htp.p('<script language = "javascript"> 
          }
         else
          { 
          theform.ghh.value = ghh;
          </script>');
          gh := false;
          htp.p('<script language = "javascript"> 
          }        
         }
          </script> </script>');  
     END IF;

*
```

Comment: You are nesting script tags? That is invalid HTML/Script! Your code is really hard to read when it is not obvious what is script and what is plsql

Answer (score 1):

You cannot split a JavaScript block over multiple `script` tags; you need to put the entire code into a single `script`.

You appear to want something like:

```sql
IF (
      dmd.is_gpid_packaged_txt(videntifier) = 'TRUE'
  AND dbcode = 'S'
  AND bsave
  AND vpreorderdt IS NULL
)
THEN
  htp.script(
       'if (voldpreorderdate != null && voldpreorderdate != "" && voldpreorderdate != "NULL")'
    || '{'
    ||   'var answer_preorder = confirm('
    ||     '"The preorder is currently live, this will not remove it from Apple.'
    ||     ' Do you want to proceed?"
    ||   ');'
    ||   'theform.vpreorderdt.value = answer_preorder?vstreetdt:voldpreorderdate;'
    || '}',
    'javascript'
  );
  bsave := FALSE;
END IF;
```

Answer (score -1):

On the first line, it says `dmd.is_gpid_packaged_txt(videntifier) = 'TRUE'` but if you want to test if something equals something else, you should use two equal signs, or ==, or three equal signs, or ===, if you want to make sure the types are equal too.

Comment: That is "an" error, but not the one the OP is asking about.

Comment: That is PL/SQL and not JavaScript on the first line. A single `=` equals is a syntactically valid PL/SQL comparison operator.